# Continue Loop after delay

Tags: java, loops, sleep

I want contniue Loop after delay , when i click this Code all Results will print in 1 second . 
I want in each Second append 1 line to TextView .

```
 String[] nos = {"\n 076","\n 078"," \n 088"};

public void buttonOnClick(View v) throws InterruptedException {
        for(int i = 0; i <nos.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j <3; j++) {
                t=(tiki.format(j));
                text = nos[i]  + t;
                txt.append(text);
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: @user902383 :D Clould you Answer?

Comment: You already use Thread.sleep...

Comment: i use that , but doesent work @Joachim

Comment: Are you sure program flow gets to `Thread.sleep(1000)`? Try with your debugger.

Comment: Program waited 1 Second for each line but printed all in last second @bathsheba

Comment: What class is `txt` and what does its `append()` method do?

Comment: @HaMidMirani: Have you actually measured it to be 1 second. Is it not actually longer than that?

Comment: @dolda2000 this isnt important , this Loop must continue after a Feedback , this is example

Comment: @HaMidMirani: It is relevant in that I suspect you're actually outputting text once a second, but doing so in the UI thread in such a manner that the output cannot be flushed to the screen until you return control to the dispatch loop.

Comment: @Dolda2000 Could you please , send correct Code?

Answer (score 0):

So you say "Program waited 1 Second for each line but printed all in last second".

As always, the program is doing exactly what you're asking it to do.

If you want snippets of the text to appear, then you need to output it piece by piece, rather than using `txt.append(text);` and outputting the whole lot at the end. Why not amend `append()` to output the text passed to it?

Comment: txt is a one TextView in Android Studio , this is a example Code of bigger App , this Loop must continue after have one Feedback from boolean beacuse work with Hardware , also this Loop must continue when have one Feedback and after go to next